# Pass dialogFragment as parameter of LiveData

Tags: android, viewmodel, android-livedata

We have lots of dialog need to show in ActivityA, ActivityA has ViewModelA, which has the live data to control when need to show dialog. Can I create dialog in ViewModelA and pass the dialog as a parameter in the LiveData?

In ViewModelA have

```
MutableLiveData<SingleLiveEvent<DialogEvent> dialogEvent;
```

For DialogEvent:

```
class DialogEvent(DialogFragment dialog)
```

When need to display dialog, update dialogEvent.

```
SomeDialogFragment fragment = new SomeDialogFragment.newInstance();
dialogEvent.postValue(new SingleLiveEvent(fragment));
```

In ActivityA observe the dialogEvent

```
viewModelA.getDialogEvent().observe {event -> event.dialog.show()}
```

Answer (score 0):

ViewModel shouldn't hold reference to Views. According to me, you can have your custom model for your dialog as LiveData and observe the data in your fragment/activity and take actions say show/hide/text on that basis from fragment/activity itself. Feel free to ask in doubt.

Comment: Yes. I know I can pass other parameters and to create and show dialog in fragment/activity. I would like to know, why it is not a good way. For the reference to view, in this case, do you mean `viewModelA.getDialogEvent()` always have a reference to one dialog event though it dismissed, and the dialog will not be garbage collected?

Comment: There are various reasons why design architectures have evolved from MVC->MVP->MVVM, providing decoupling, testability re-usability etc. Basically, ViewModel stores and manage UI-related data in a lifecycle conscious way.  https://android.jlelse.eu/dive-deep-into-androids-viewmodel-android-architecture-components-e0a7ded26f70 and many other articles are there which may help you.